# Why does my well pump pressure intermittently drop to 0?

Tags: pressure

#### Situation:

Three homes share one 2500 gal water tank 'main'. It's been that way for the 16 years we've lived here. In the past we've had some, but not many problems [broken main at someones residence / tank overflow, etc.]

About 2 months ago we had our own 2500 gallon above-ground water tank hooked up. It is set up to run as our primary water source. If, for some reason, it fails we can switch back to the previous setup while the problem is resolved.

#### Hardware:

- Goulds Model 18GBC10 1 hp pump
- 1" PVC stepped down from 1 1/2" from 'main' source
- tank bladder set to factory specs [don't know what that is]
- check valve prior to water into pump

#### Problem:

The pump regulator was set to start @ 48PSI and stop at 62PSI. Intermittently, when the pump hits this 42PSI threshold, the pressure drops immediately to 0, stopping the pump.

I've heard/read that it can be caused by an empty tank or a leak. The tank is totally full and I don't believe we have a leak because even on the 'main' system the pump next door does not cycle on/off as though there is a leak. This has been going on since the installation.

Things that have been done:

1. the regulator was replaced twice. First time because it 'chattered'. The second because it had burn marks on the contacts. Don't know the brand but can find out if necessary. This has not resolved the problem. I'll need to get the cycling PSIs next time I'm out and recording this problem.
2. I've  contacted the manufacturer of the pump and got some good literature but because I don't understand this stuff it's Greek to me.

When we're on the 'main' there are no issues. When we switch over to the new system, it can be days or hours before failure.

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Thanks. Alan <><

Comment: It almost sounds like a water logged pressure tank, where the pressure has no air pressure as a buffer.  Does the pressure gauge go up and down fast?  Some pressure switches have a safety that if the pressure drops, then it tends to shut off the pump in case of a pipe leaking.  Water logged tanks make it look like a leaking pipe.

Comment: In that case you'll see a rapid drop from 62 to 42.

Comment: I removed the note about the first problem since it's been resolved and doesn't seem to be involved with the current issue. Also tweaked the formatting and actually asked a question. In general, though, very well asked for a first question!

Comment: Thank you Ecnerwal! Your analysis was the key to getting this resolved. I passed your comments as well as other research I had done to the fellow who set the system up. He either forgot to set the pressures or did not set them correctly to begin with. He came over the next day and adjusted the pressure on the bladder. Since then we haven't had a water problem. Bless you!!!   Alan <><

Answer (score 0):

This is typical  of having too much pressure in the pressure tank bladder.

If you are cutting in at 42 PSI, the tank air pressure should typically be set to 39-40 PSI with no pressure on the water side. The purpose is to provide some reserve water as the pump kicks on, since that's not instant.

If the pressure is too high, the tank runs out of water as the pump is starting when the rate of water use is high enough. A lower set pressure will provide more reserve water to cover that case.

If your air gauge and water gauge have a slight disagreement about pressure it can appear to be set correctly and not actually be. In that case, follow the behavior, and take another pound or so off the air side until the behavior resolves.

You can verify that the tank is working as intended by allowing the system to come to pressure at 62, shutting off all outlets (and the inlet if the feed tank gravity-feeds the pump), turning off the pump, and draining into a container that allows you to measure the volume. Your tank will have a published chart of drawdown (typically for 60-40, 50-30, and 40-20 PSI) and your volume should be near the 40-60 value. You can *also* pay attention to how much water you get between 42 and the water running out. Likewise, the precise point (according to the water side gauge) where it suddenly drops to zero as that happens.